# How can I build the Xcode-generated Swift Package Workspace with xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

When you open a `Package.swift` file, Xcode will generate a workspace with the path: `.swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace`.

I'd like to use `xcodebuild` to build this but it does not seem to work. The error messages are not helpful, just tells me that clang failed.

The actual command I'm running is:

```
xcodebuild -workspace .swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace -scheme MyLibrary-Package -sdk iphonesimulator OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-D SWIFT_PACKAGE"
```

Funny enough, trying to build a scheme that describes an individual target works:

```
xcodebuild -workspace .swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace -scheme SpecificTarget -sdk iphonesimulator OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-D SWIFT_PACKAGE"
```

Am I missing some build flags needed to build the combination scheme? Has anyone else struggled with this and have any advice?

**Note:**

The ultimate goal here is to be able to verify that my Swift Package builds in CI. If there is an easier way to achieve this goal then I'm happy to go another route. (The easier might just be multiple commands to build the individual targets but this is less robust)

Comment: Try `swift build` in the package root, this should help you validate

Comment: @Cristik this will definitely not work. The project is too complex. It would require a MUCH more complex command to be able to build this using swift build alone.